# How do I make a function call with switch statements after the user chooses their option?

Tags: c++, function, geometry, switch-statement

[image]

I have tried to make a function call here but I don't know what is going wrong. I am getting an error:

> Uninitialized local variable 'area' used

We are required to use a `switch` case. If anyone can help fix this, it will be great.

```cpp
// Include Section
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

//Function prototype
double rectangle(double, double);
double triangle(double, double);
double circle(double);

// Main Program
int main()
{
    //Variable declaration
    int choice;
    const double PI = 3.14159; //pi
    double area;
    double length, //length for rectangle
            width; //width for rectangle
    double height; //height for triangle
    double base; //base for triangle
    double radius; //radius for circle

    //Give choices
    cout << "Welcome to Geometry Calculator \n";
    cout << "Pick one option from the following: \n";
    cout << "1. Calculate the Area of a Rectangle \n";
    cout << "2. Calculate the Area of a Triangle \n";
    cout << "3. Calculate the Area of a Circle \n";
    cout << "4. Quit \n\n";

    //input choice
    cout << "Enter your choice (1-4): ";
    cin >> choice;

    //Input Validation
    while (choice <= 0 || choice > 4)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a valid menu chice: ";
        cin >> choice;
    }

    //Switch statement
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1: //rectangle
            cout << "Enter the LENGTH of your Rectangle: ";
            cin >> length;
            cout << "Enter the WIDTH of your Rectangle: ";
            cin >> width;
            rectangle(length, width);
            //function
            break;

        case 2: //Triangle
            cout << "Enter the LENGTH of the base of your Triangle: ";
            cin >> base;
            cout << "Enter the HEIGHT of your Triangle: ";
            cin >> height;
            triangle(base, height);
            return 0;
            break;

        case 3: //Circle
            cout << "Enter the RADIUS of your Circle: ";
            cin >> radius;
            circle(radius);
            return 0;
            //calculation
            break;

        case 4: //quit
            cout << "You chose to quit. Thanks for using my program! \n\n";
    }
    return 0;
}

//function call
void triangle(double base, double height);
{
    area = base * height * 0.5;
    cout << "The AREA of your Triangle is " << area << ". \n\n";
}

void circle(double radius);
{
    area = PI * radius * radius;
    cout << "The AREA of your Circle is " << area << ". \n\n";
}

double fc = rectangle(double length, double width);
{
    area = length * width;
    cout << "The area of the rectangle is " << area << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple issues here:

---

On the function definitions, the trailing semicolon should not be there:

```
void triangle(double base, double height);  // <-- remove this semicolon
{
    area = base * height * 0.5;
    cout << "The AREA of your Triangle is " << area << ". \n\n";
}
```

This error is present on the other definitions as well.  A semicolon terminates a function forward declaration (at the top of the file) but when defining the function, the braces replace it.

---

You also declare the three functions `triangle`/`circle`/`rectangle` to return `double` but in the implementation you define them to return `void` which doesn't match.  This is likely the source of the specific error you're getting.

Change either the forward declarations to match the definitions, or vice-versa.

---

These three functions also attempt to assign to an `area` variable which is not in scope.  This variable must be declared in those functions if you want to use it there.

Note that the `area` variable in `main()` is not reachable from these functions.

---

The definition for `rectangle` begins with a variable declaration, which makes no sense:

```
double fc = rectangle(double length, double width);
```

This is parsed as a declaration of a global `fc` variable which is initialized to the result of calling the `rectangle` function, but the argument syntax is incorrect so parsing would fail there.  Presumably this should read:

```
void rectangle(double length, double width)
```

or

```
double rectangle(double length, double width)
```

---

The function `circle()` refers to a symbol `PI` but this is not in scope. (You declare `PI` inside of `main()` so it is only visible within that function. You can fix this by moving it into global scope.)

Comment: I tried removing the semicolons but still getting the same errors. I have added a picture of the errors if that helps.

Comment: @qwerty That's because there is more than one error; see the rest of my answer.

Comment: yeah I realized the mistake in rectangle definition. can you see any other mistakes using the error image?

Comment: Could you also please explain what void is used for?

Comment: @qwerty When used as a return type, void indicates the absence of a return value at all; void functions return no value.

Comment: Thank you so much. It has reduced to just 1 error now that says "uninitialized local variable 'area' used"

Comment: @qwerty I'm not sure where that would be; I suggest that it's related to a change that you've made somewhere. I don't see any usages of an uninitialized variable called `area` in your question, so this problem likely only exists in the version of the code you currently have, which I cannot see.

Comment: @qwerty In the version of the code I saw, you declared `area` and `PI` as _parameters_ and not local variables.